# Reduce chart code

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I want to reduce chart code because I have too many variables which I believe can be reduced.

**Object to store data:**

```
public class EventsObj
{
    private String date;
    private int info;
    private int error;
    private int warning;
    private int critical;

    public EventsObj()
    {
    }

    public EventsObj(String date, int info, int error, int warning, int critical)
    {
        this.date = date;
        this.info = info;
        this.error = error;
        this.warning = warning;
        this.critical = critical;
    }

    public String getDate()
    {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date)
    {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getInfo()
    {
        return info;
    }
................
```

**List for data from SQL query:**

```
    List<EventsObj> eventsObj = new ArrayList<>();

 eventsObj.add(new EventsObj(String.valueOf(rs.getTimestamp("EVENT_DATE")), rs.getInt("INFO"), rs.getInt("WARN"), rs.getInt("CRITICAL"), rs.getInt("ERROR")));
```

But when I want to use the data in Pie chart I use this ugly code:

```
ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

int info = 0;
        int error = 0;
        int warning = 0;
        int critical = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < eventsObj.size(); i++)
        {
            EventsObj get = eventsObj.get(i);
            info = get.getInfo() + info;
            error = get.getError() + error;
            warning = get.getWarning() + warning;
            critical = get.getCritical() + critical;
        }

        pieChartData.add(new PieChart.Data("Info", info));
        pieChartData.add(new PieChart.Data("Error", error));
        pieChartData.add(new PieChart.Data("Warning", warning));
        pieChartData.add(new PieChart.Data("Critical", critical));


        final PieChart chart = new PieChart(pieChartData);
```

Can you propose some more easy solution to get the data from the List and insert it  into the Pie Chart?

Comment: You shouldn't store date-time as a string, use a `Date` field instead. Other than that, it's somewhat unclear what your question / problem is.

Comment: I agree. For the main question: Can you propose something?

Comment: Is something not working with your current solution?

Comment: You might believe that some variables can be removed, but we have no idea what the existing variables mean; how can we say what can be removed?

Comment: Just cosmetic: you can change `info = get.getInfo() + info;` to `info += get.getInfo();`

Comment: @MickMnemonic it's working but I would like to remove int info = 0;
        int error = 0;
        int warning = 0;
        int critical = 0;

Answer (score 1):

Arguably at the risk of sacrificing some readability (I guess that depends on how familiar you are with Java 8 features), you could do something like

```
private <T> PieChart.Data createPieData(List<T> items, String name,
        ToIntFunction<T> function) {

    int value = items.stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(function));
    return new PieChart.Data(name, value);
}
```

and then

```
final PieChart chart = new PieChart();

chart.getData().add(createPieData(eventsObj, "Info", EventsObj::getInfo));
chart.getData().add(createPieData(eventsObj, "Error", EventsObj::getError));
chart.getData().add(createPieData(eventsObj, "Warning", EventsObj::getWarning));
chart.getData().add(createPieData(eventsObj, "Critical", EventsObj::getCritical));
```

But, to be honest, I don't really see what's wrong with your original code anyway.